# Primefaces RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset for selectonemenu

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use Primefaces 5 and I would like reset a selectonemenu to default value.

I have a paging structure so:

```
    <p:fragment>

    <p:tabView id="tabview1" cache="false" dynamic="true" >
        <p:tab title="One" id="tab1">
            <ui:include src="tab1.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Two" id="tab2" >
            <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</p:fragment>
```

Then, tab1.xhtml for example is this:

```
<h:form id="frm1">
    <table id="tbl1">          
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="select1"
                                 value="#{bean.test}" 
                                 valueChangeListener="#{bean.setXXX}"
                                 var="var1" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." 
                                  itemValue="#{null}" />
                    <f:selectItems  var="var2"
                                    value="#{bean.list}" 
                                    itemLabel="#{var2.label}"
                                    itemValue="#{var2}"/>
                    <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" update="@this"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

I believe that for reset my selectonemenu I can write in my setXXX method: 
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("tabView1:tab1:frm1:tbl1:select1");

Doesn't work and I have excpetion "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Any idea? What is correct path for reset?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand what you mean by reset is to establish again the default value to the select menu, don't you?

In that case the thing is very simple. You just need to modify the current value of the selected item. So, in your Backing Bean "bean", in the  setXXX method just reset the original value of the attribute="#{bean.**test**}".

When ajax updates the combo it will refresh the recent default value test.

Comment: Which is code to use? I would like set my selectonemenu to "Select..."

Comment: In your method setXXX you should reset your test value: for example    test = new Test();

Answer (score 0):

You are referring the component using `tabView1:tab1:frm1:tbl1:select1`.

There are 2 errors in it.

In JSF/Primefaces the components which implement [javax.faces.component.NamingContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) are the only components that attach their id to the inner components.

So `p:tab` and `table` (not a JSF component at all) are not one of those components.

From your code only component that implement `javax.faces.component.NamingContainer` are `p:tabView` and `h:form`.

So your `p:selectOneMenu` id will be just be `tabview1:frm1:select1`

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("tabview1:frm1:select1");
```

This you can look it up from your Browser's Inspect Element.

[image]

and Remember to update the component once you `reset`, which you can do it from ManagedBean itself using `Requestcontext`

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("tabview1:frm1:select1");
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your details. I tried, exception there isn't but my select doesn't reset. For now I solved with adding a object binding in bean class

Comment: Like I said you have to update the component once reset using `RequestContext`. Reset using `binding` will also works fine.